# ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions in VAE

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I wanted to change the VAE model in [Keras VAE Tutorials](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/) from Conv2D to Conv1D, but the error above came out. The input data is as follows:

```
x.train shape:  (7511302, 20, 1)
```

Code:

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""
    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


##### Encoder
latent_dim = 2
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=5, kernel_regularizer='l2')(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=2, kernel_regularizer='l2')(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

##### Decoder
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((2, 32))(x)
x = layers.Conv1DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=2, kernel_regularizer='l2')(x)
x = layers.Conv1DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', strides=5, kernel_regularizer='l2')(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()

##### Define the VAE as a Model with a custom train_step
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")
    
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(x_train, epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [142], in <cell line: 9>()
      7 vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
      8 vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
----> 9 vae.fit(x_train,epochs=30, batch_size=128)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/ae_model/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File /var/folders/ql/_8w93xjx0js3w2r8d3sq13w0yd93j4/T/__autograph_generated_file2_wnqlaa.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

Input In [141], in VAE.train_step(self, data)
     22 z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
     23 reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
     24 reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
---> 25     tf.reduce_sum(
     26         keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
     27     )
     28 )
     29 kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
     30 kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/1004831/miniforge3/envs/ae_model/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/1004831/miniforge3/envs/ae_model/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/1004831/miniforge3/envs/ae_model/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "<ipython-input-141-373258cf77cd>", line 25, in train_step
        tf.reduce_sum(

    ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions. for '{{node Sum}} = Sum[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](Mean, Sum/reduction_indices)' with input shapes: [?,20], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2>.
```

Comment: Try replacing `tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2))` with `tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=1)` in `train_step()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Also, I tried to apply modelpath, earlyStopping , mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss in fit method. and the error came out.

# vae.fit(x_train,epochs=30, batch_size=128). --> history = vae.fit(x_train, batch_size=128, epochs=50, validation_split=0.25, verbose=1, callbacks=[earlyStopping, mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss]).  the error is followed

Comment: raise NotImplementedError('Unimplemented `tf.keras.Model.call()`: if you '

    NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling layer "vae_4" (type VAE).
    
    Unimplemented `tf.keras.Model.call()`: if you intend to create a `Model` with the Functional API, please provide `inputs` and `outputs` arguments. Otherwise, subclass `Model` with an overridden `call()` method.
    
    Call arguments received by layer "vae_4" (type VAE):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 20, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None