# Invalid argument: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 1024 vs. 4096: [64,1024] [4096,200] in VAE derived from GAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I’m trying to combine pretrained Encoder from VAE with pretrained Generator from GAN (from a tutorial) to train them together.

Source code for GAN - https://github.com/davidADSP/GDL_code/blob/master/models/GAN.py

Source code for VAE - https://github.com/davidADSP/GDL_code/blob/master/models/WGANGP.py

My main code is following:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from models.WGANGPVAE import WGANGPVAE
from models.VAE import VariationalAutoencoder
from utils.loaders import load_celeb

# run params
WT_FILE_NAME = 'weights-214.54.h5'
EXT_DATA = './data_source/'
SECTION = 'gan_vae'
RUN_ID = '0004'
DATA_NAME = 'celeba'
SOURCE_DATA = '../content/data/img_align_celeba/'
RUN_FOLDER = 'run/{}/'.format(SECTION)
RUN_FOLDER += '_'.join([RUN_ID, DATA_NAME])

LEARNING_RATE = 0.0002 
R_LOSS_FACTOR = 10000

if not os.path.exists(RUN_FOLDER):
os.mkdir(RUN_FOLDER)
os.mkdir(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'viz'))
os.mkdir(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'images'))
os.mkdir(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'weights'))

BATCH_SIZE = 64
IMAGE_SIZE = 64
INPUT_DIM = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)
H_DIM = 200

x_train = load_celeb(SOURCE_DATA, IMAGE_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, True)

print(x_train[0][0][0])
print(np.min(x_train[0][0][1]))
print(np.max(x_train[0][0][2]))

plt.imshow((x_train[0][0][0]+1)/2)

gan = WGANGPVAE(input_dim = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)
, critic_conv_filters = [64,128,256,512]
, critic_conv_kernel_size = [5,5,5,5]
, critic_conv_strides = [2,2,2,2]
, critic_batch_norm_momentum = None
, critic_activation = 'leaky_relu'
, critic_dropout_rate = None
, critic_learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE
, generator_initial_dense_layer_size = (4, 4, 512)
, generator_upsample = [1,1,1,1]
, generator_conv_filters = [256,128,64,3]
, generator_conv_kernel_size = [5,5,5,5]
, generator_conv_strides = [2,2,2,2]
, generator_batch_norm_momentum = 0.9
, generator_activation = 'leaky_relu'
, generator_dropout_rate = None
, generator_learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE
, optimiser = 'adam'
, grad_weight = 10
, z_dim = H_DIM
, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

gan.load_weights(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'weights/weights.h5'))

vae = VariationalAutoencoder(
input_dim = INPUT_DIM
, encoder_conv_filters=[32,64,64, 64]
, encoder_conv_kernel_size=[3,3,3,3]
, encoder_conv_strides=[2,2,2,2]
, decoder_conv_t_filters=[64,64,32,3]
, decoder_conv_t_kernel_size=[3,3,3,3]
, decoder_conv_t_strides=[2,2,2,2]
, z_dim=H_DIM
, use_batch_norm=True
, use_dropout=True)

if os.path.exists(EXT_DATA+'weights/'+WT_FILE_NAME):
vae.load_weights(os.path.join(EXT_DATA,'weights/'+WT_FILE_NAME))
print('Data loaded')

gan.build_vae(vae)
gan.compile_vae(LEARNING_RATE, R_LOSS_FACTOR)

EPOCHS = 7000
PRINT_EVERY_N_BATCHES = 5
N_CRITIC = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 64

gan.train_vae(
x_train
, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
, epochs = EPOCHS
, run_folder = RUN_FOLDER
, print_every_n_batches = PRINT_EVERY_N_BATCHES
)
```

Also, modified a bit WGANGP class to build, compile and train a combined model:

```
def compile_vae(self, learning_rate, r_loss_factor):
    if not self.vae_created:
        raise VaeCreationError('VAE needed to be built first prior to compile!')
        
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate

    ### COMPILATION
    def vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        r_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis = [1,2,3])
        return r_loss_factor * r_loss

    def vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        kl_loss =  -0.5 * K.sum(1 + self.log_var - K.square(self.mu) - K.exp(self.log_var), axis = 1)
        return kl_loss

    def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        r_loss = vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred)
        kl_loss = vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
        return  r_loss + kl_loss

    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = vae_loss,  metrics = [vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss])        
    
def build_vae(self, vae):
    if self.vae_created:
        raise VaeCreationError('GAN was converted already.')
    if not self.loaded:
        raise VaeCreationError('Model need to be trained or weights loaded first.')
    
    self.encoder = vae.encoder
    
    self.mu = vae.mu
    self.log_var = vae.log_var
    self.encoder_mu_log_var = vae.encoder_mu_log_var
    
    ### THE DECODER
    self.mu = vae.mu
    self.log_var = vae.log_var
    self.encoder_mu_log_var = vae.encoder_mu_log_var
    
    ### THE DECODER
    self.decoder = self.generator
    
    ### THE FULL VAE
    model_input = self.encoder.input
    model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder.output)
    
    self.vae = Model(model_input, model_output)
    self.vae_created = True
    
def train_vae(self, x_train, batch_size, epochs, run_folder, print_every_n_batches = 100, initial_epoch = 0, lr_decay = 1):

    custom_callback = CustomCallback(run_folder, print_every_n_batches, initial_epoch, self)
    lr_sched = step_decay_schedule(initial_lr=self.learning_rate, decay_factor=lr_decay, step_size=1)
    
    checkpoint_filepath=os.path.join(run_folder, "weights/weights-{epoch:03d}-{loss:.2f}.h5")
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, save_weights_only = True, verbose=1)
    checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(run_folder, 'weights/weights.h5'), save_weights_only = True, verbose=1)

    callbacks_list = [checkpoint1, checkpoint2, custom_callback, lr_sched]
    
    idx = np.random.randint(0,len(x_train.index_array), batch_size)
    true_imgs = x_train[idx.all()][0]

    loss = self.vae.train_on_batch(true_imgs, true_imgs)
    print(loss)
```

Combined model was created and compiled successfully and just after training starts, this thrown the following error:

> 2023-04-21 11:57:27.383001: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version
> 8201 Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\dev\ML\VAE+GAN_faces\WGANGPVAEtest.py", line 170, in
>
> , print_every_n_batches = PRINT_EVERY_N_BATCHES
>
> File "C:\dev\ML\VAE+GAN_faces\models\WGANGPVAE.py", line 529, in
> train_vae
> loss = self.vae.train_on_batch(true_imgs, true_imgs)
>
> File
> "C:\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py",
> line 1076, in train_on_batch
> outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line
> 4032, in **call**
> run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
>
> File
> "C:\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
> line 1480, in **call**
> run_metadata_ptr)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Invalid argument:
> In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 1024 vs. 4096: [64,1024] [4096,200] 0 0
> [[{{node mu/MatMul}}]]
> [[model_1_2/batch_normalization_2/cond/else/_759/FusedBatchNormV3/_1319]]
> (1) Invalid argument: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 1024 vs. 4096:
> [64,1024] [4096,200] 0 0   [[{{node mu/MatMul}}]] 0 successful
> operations. 0 derived errors ignored.

I understand that this is potentially can be related to custom VAE-related loss functions (vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss), but having them as a part of the original VAE encoder, which copied without any changes, so even don’t know from what to start troubleshooting.

Other than that, have already checked this question - [ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions in VAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530922/valueerror-invalid-reduction-dimension-2-for-input-with-2-dimensions-in-vae), which seems can be one of relevant, prior to posting this question and similar ones but didn’t find any hints on how troubleshoot errors above, plus error messages and/or overall context seem to be different from this one.